# Eclipse + GDB: Cannot find bounds of current function

Tags: eclipse, gdb

I have problems debugging a program in Eclipse 2019-03 using GDB on Windows 10 with MinGW.

Whenever I stop in the program, I get the error message `ERROR: Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-step 1". Cannot find bounds of current function`.

I got this also when debugging a new C/C++ project with just printing a line to the console, so it seems unrelated to the actual program that was executing.

Both programs could be debugged fine when running `gdb` manually on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question: the problem was caused by a number of watch expressions that I had configured in Eclipse. I discovered this when I enabled GDB traces in Eclipse to see the MI commands between Eclipse and GDB.

Removing all watch expressions in Eclipse solved the problem for me.

Comment: thanks for this answer, this worked for me as well.